# Access Object By a Single URL with the Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model

Does the SharePoint Client Object Model have any method to access an object (List, Document, etc.) with just a single URL and valid credentials?

Essentially, I want to access an object (*http://example.com/sites/Site1/Lib1/Sample.pdf*) programmatically like this:

```
var credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass", "domain");
using (var sp = new ClientContext("http://example.com/sites/Site1/") { Credentials = credentials })
{
    var file = sp.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Lib1/Sample.pdf");
    sp.Load(file);
    sp.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I want to do this, except without knowing ahead of time which part of the URL corresponds to the site and which part points me to the object. So, I'm wondering if I have to make my own logic for this or if the Client Object Model has something for me to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no "get by URL" method for lists in the client object model
>   that I am aware of.
>
> About the closest thing you have is a **GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl**
>   on the Web object:
>
> ```
> ClientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url)
> ```
>
> Depending on what you want to do this might work for
>   you...unfortunately you can't get the parent list from the folder
>   object like you can in the .NET api.

Source - [Similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/how-to-get-list-by-url-using-client-object-model/17504#17504)

Since you can't get a list by URL so I would assume you can't get a document by url either, but you can try doing it this way tho,

```
var fileItem = Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("server/relative/url");

context.Load(fileItem); //you will probably need to load the ListItemAllFields property here.
context.ExecuteQuery();

var listItem = fileItem.ListItemAllFields; 

Console.WriteLine(listItem["Title"]);
```

Source - [getlistitemstrurl-equivalent-for-clientcontext](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43833/getlistitemstrurl-equivalent-for-clientcontext)

Hope it helps :)