# How to get List by Url using SharePoint 2013 CSOM

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

SharePoint 2013 CSOM API contains the following methods for accessing List object:

- [ListCollection.GetById method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.getbyid(v=office.15).aspx) - returns the list with the
  specified list identifier
- [ListCollection.GetByTitle method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.getbytitle(v=office.15).aspx) - returns the list with the
  specified title from the collection

For example:

```
var listTitle = "Tasks";
using(var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     ctx.Load(list);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

From another hand, SSOM API contains [SPWeb.GetList method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) to gets the list that is associated with the specified server-relative URL.

The question is: how to *effectively* load `List` by server-relative URL in CSOM?

Comment: Vadim, if you had mention using another method other than CSOM, then yes.  The SOAP services has it a method that you can use - SiteData.GetURLSegments. I wrote about it here: http://paultavares.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/how-to-get-information-about-a-sharepoint-list-item-using-its-url/

Comment: ListCollection lists = context.Web.Lists;
context.Load(lists, all => all.Include(l => l.RootFolder)); It does not work either!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This seems to be pretty close in performance:

```
context.Load(lists, all => all
  .Where(l => l.RootFolder.Name == "MyListUrl")
  .Include(l => l.Id));
context.ExecuteQuery();
list = lists.Single();
```

If you need to get this by server-relative url you would need to parse the web url and list url first.

Comment: Had to take some performance tests away from the answer because of high variance. Anyways there doesn't seem to be big difference in performance (~0-25%).

Comment: Cool, also added an extension method here: Not so pretty with all the parsing..

Comment: Took the extension method away because didn't invent how to protect against user giving a subfolder as an argument (instead of the actual list/library RootfolderName), without executing query more than once.

Answer (score 33):

For those who are still looking for the answer. SharePoint 2013 (<del>since SP1 at least</del> see **UPD** below) contains special method [Web.GetList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getlist.aspx). It accepts site-relative url for the list, i.e. `site/dev/lists/mylist`.

Sample code for .NET object model:

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp2013dev/sites/dev");
var list = ctx.Web.GetList("sites/dev/lists/Addresses");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();    
Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
```

The same situation for JavaScript object model (except the fact that msdn documentation is lacking and you don't find this method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245288.aspx) at the moment of writing this, May 2015):

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().getList("/sites/dev/Lists/Addresses"); 
context.load(list);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
    alert("loaded!"); 
    }, function() { 
    alert("failed!"); 
});
```

Now we don't need all this hacks with folder or list properties.

**UPD:**

Just tested that this method is not included in SP1. It works starting from February 2015 CU (sorry, can't check the exact CU number)

Comment: Oh, finally, i suppose it should be considered as the most accurate answer   then.Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find this method in the latest NuGet download of the DLL. Instead, I found an version of the DLL on my dev server (patched to March 2015 CU) but it didn't work for Production which is only SP1.

Comment: @PeterX, you're correct, unfortunately SP1 doesn't contain this method, I've already mentioned it. It seems it was included at the end of 2014 or at the beginning of 2015.

Comment: I can confirm that it also works with absolute urls

Comment: And as it's included in the CSOM, now the REST endpoint are also updated: `_api/web/getList('/sites/yoursite/yourlibraryOrList')`

Answer (score 19):

Yet another version to load `List` by server relative Url using CSOM.

The solution consists of the following steps:

1. Retrieve list Folder object using  Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl 
   method
2. Retrieve List by specifying `List ID` stored in `vti_listname` property from `Folder.Properties` object

Code:

```
static class WebExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load List by server relative Url
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web"></param>
    /// <param name="listUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List LoadListByUrl(this Web web, string listUrl)
    {
        var ctx = web.Context;
        var listFolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(listUrl);
        ctx.Load(listFolder.Properties);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        var listId = new Guid(listFolder.Properties["vti_listname"].ToString());
        var list = web.Lists.GetById(listId);
        ctx.Load(list);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using(var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,securePassword);
    var tasksList = ctx.Web.LoadListByUrl("Lists/Tasks");
    Console.WriteLine(tasksList.Title);
}
```

**Cons**:

1. Only SharePoint 2013 CSOM is supported
2. Requires two separate requests to server

Comment: Nice usage of out-of-the-box methods, and no need to parse server-relative url.

Comment: Also you can use rest api to get list id instead of relying on property bags:  `http://sharepoint/_api/web/lists/?$expand=RootFolder&$filter=RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl eq '/Lists/MyCoolList'&$select=ID`. It also should reduce client-server traffic

Comment: I get the error `Error 2 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder' does not contain a definition for 'Properties' and no extension method 'Properties' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` any thoughts?

Comment: I had an out-of-date `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` DLL. I couldn't find any MS downloads and the NuGet installer seemed to have a bug, so I harvested the DLLs from the NuGet download and added the references manually.

Comment: I now get a `ServerException` / `File Not Found.` error, using either an absolute URL or a relative URL.

Comment: @PeterX, if you have site/test url for site collection, then you rest query should be: `http://sharepoint/sites/test/_api/web/lists/?$expand=RootFolder&$filter=RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl eq '/sites/test/Lists/TestList'&$select=ID`. Just copy paste it into the browser (with valid sharepoint and list urls) and will see the result.

Answer (score 2):

I unfortunately couldn't get any of the above working, so I used an ugly hack:

```
public static List GetListByUrl(ClientContext context, string listUrl)
        {
            List result = null;

            ListCollection lists = context.Web.Lists;
            context.Load(lists, all => all.Include(l => l.RootFolder));            
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            string listUrlPartial = new Uri(listUrl).PathAndQuery.ToLower().Replace("%20", " ");
            foreach (List list in lists)
            {
                string thisListUrlPartial = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower().Replace("%20", " ");
                if (listUrlPartial.StartsWith(thisListUrlPartial))
                {
                    result = list;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Of course, your mileage will vary. Recommend upgrading to latest SharePoint patch to get the new method (as per @Kai's answer), but unfortunately I don't have that option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have SP1 for my SharePoint, but this worked for me:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("absolute url to sites that contains the list");

var IssueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("title of the list");
```