# Sharepoint 2013 Multi lingual environment add-in development issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

My client has multi language SharePoint 2013 environment.I am developing a sharepoint hosted app for my client, but when i try to access any library or list using its name e.g. getByTitle('site pages')...it is giving me an error(List not found) in sites with language other than English.
Please suggest me any solution how to access list or libraries in different sites with different languages.

Comment: you can use "GetList" method and use internal name instead.

Comment: "GetList" is not available in client side code(javascript). If you able to do it can you please give me any reference link or a  complete example. Thanks....@BhaskarDhone

Comment: ohh My bad ,  I just missed SharePoint Online. Instead of getByTitle  , you can user 'getById(guid);' Let me know if it helps

Comment: Actually i have to create a single add-in solution for different sites. Different sites will have different GUID for the list with same name. Example 'site pages' library will have different GUID for each site. Thats why i can't use GUID. @BhaskarDhone

Answer (score 1):

While browsing through other similar Stackexchange questions I found this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116807/how-to-get-list-by-url-using-sharepoint-2013-csom) containing the exact answer to your question although [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245288.aspx) doesn't say anything about it.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().getList("/sites/dev/Lists/Addresses"); 
context.load(list);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
  alert("loaded!"); 
  }, function() { 
  alert("failed!"); 
});
```

I've tried the code in my console and I was able to load a list based on the url no matter if I changed the title or not.