# How to get items from a SharePoint List by list URL path using Javascript REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, odata

Using JavaScript REST API, we can get a list by URL path. Thus:

```
http://vmdevsharepoint:12345/_api/web/lists/
```

Concatenating with this:

```
?$expand=RootFolder&$filter‌​=RootFolder/ServerRe‌​lativeUrl eq '/Lists/MyList'
```

That result this:

```
http://vmdevsharepoint:12345/_api/web/lists/?$expand=RootFolder&$filter‌​=RootFolder/ServerRe‌​lativeUrl eq '/Lists/MyList'
```

It works properly!

**But how to get items from that list at same time?** At same line of code too!

I tried to concatenate the above code with this:

```
&/items?$select=Title,DocType,DocNumber,Author
```

**Resulting this** (final line of code to copy and test in your environment):

```
http://vmdevsharepoint:12345/_api/web/lists/?$expand=RootFolder&$filter‌​=RootFolder/ServerRe‌​lativeUrl eq '/Lists/MyList'&/items?$select=Title,DocType,DocNumber,Author
```

But it does not worked!

**Can someone help-me?**

**Update:**
For context purposes, you can see that reference: [How to get List by Url using SharePoint 2013 CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116807/how-to-get-list-by-url-using-sharepoint-2013-csom/231577#231577)

Answer (score 1):

your query is extracting the lists, 
if you want to extract the list items you need to wo write a new query to request an specific list and then extract its items :

http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListTitle')/items

more info:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Comment: The list's title can be updated by the customer and I want to avoid any error in my code if it's occur! Because of that, I want to get list by Url and get their items :)
How to solve this using JS REST API?

Comment: then you can use the GUID, that one never changes
or also you can use the Title extracted from the previous call, this way you'll always get the current TITLE

Comment: Additionally, Rest doesn't work like CSOM where you can perform more than 1 request in 1 single call.

you'll have to write an additional query for each new request you want to make, that's the reason you cannot get the items when you are requesting a list